# Optimizing a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, optimization

So, I was standing in line for a Paramore concert for a very long time this past weekend because the boyfriend wanted to be up front during the show. I got to thinking, what would be the optimal time to show up for a concert to minimize both the time waiting and the number of people in front of you? I immediately thought of modelling concert goers' arrival times as a Poisson process.
We can represent a given attendee's arrival time (in hours before the show begins) as X ~ Pois(λ). So, x = 0 means they show up as the show is starting, x = 3 means they showed up three hours before the show started, etc. So, if I'm not mistaken, it follows that if I wanted to arrive before 80% of the attendees, I should solve the following:

$$ 0.2 \leq 1 - \sum_{k = 0}^{K} P(x < k) $$

Which yields

```
> qpois(p = 0.8, lambda = 2)
[1] 3
```

Therefore, I should show up at least three hours before the show begins in order to arrive before 80% of the attendees.
Where I'm having trouble is instead of picking an arbitrary time or percentage, I would like to optimize this process. That is, find a value for x such that x and p (number of people in front of you in line) are minimized. Any comments/suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be missing all assumptions about the distribution of $\lambda$ among the attendees--or do you assume they all have the same value of $\lambda$ and arrivals are independent? Also, there's no reason to suppose that both the time waiting and number of people in front of you can simultaneously be optimized, unless you are the only people to attend the concert! A clearer statement, then, of what it is you are trying to minimize is needed in order for this question to be answerable.

Comment: For simplicity, I was making the (erroneous) assumption that arrivals are independent. I wanted to minimize the waiting time, but if that's the only thing I wanted to minimize, wouldn't the answer be the obvious answer of 0 (show up when the concert is starting)?

Comment: Your model is missing key information its formulation. If you show up at time $0$, you don't get to the front and so you fail to meet your objective--but there's nothing in the model that actually states, much less quantifies, your objective (of being "up front"). If you show up $1000$ hours before the concert, maybe you're at the front but you wait a long time. You need to quantify what you're trying to achieve and you need to be more explicit about the assumptions you are making.

Comment: Right, I was having trouble figuring out how to do that. I was thinking about doing something along the lines of defining a function [; f(x, n) ;] that penalizes for a long wait time and a a lot of people in front of you. Something along the lines of [; f(x, n) = (c_{1}*x - c_{2}*n)^{2} ;] where x = wait time, n = number of people in front of you, and c1 and c2 are constants. Then I could minimize this? Idk...

Comment: You might want to think along the following lines: define "up front" to mean that you are within the first $M$ people in line (let your partner determine $M$ before you go out). You need to attach a cost to waiting *and* a cost to failing to be among the first $M$. Your distributional assumptions on arrival times translate into a distribution of the sum of those costs. You might want to arrive at the gate at a time of least expected cost. This is only one of many possible formulations of this problem--you need to work out what the problem really *is* before you ask it!

Comment: BTW, if you replace `[;` and `;]` by `$` your $\TeX$ expressions will be nicely rendered.

Comment: Awesome--I'll think about this further and see if I can come up with a solution (or rather, what the problem actually is ;P). Also, thanks for the $\TeX$ info!

Comment: Time is generally taken to be a rational number, not a whole number of hours. You need a continuous distribution like a gamma distribution for your model.